# Android Help with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-3.0-honeycomb

My application works fine in all versions of Android except It is failing because I am making network calls on the main thread. My code below fails on `url.openStream()` and I guess I need to make this call on a separate thread. Also, I created this class `Utilities` so I could reference functions that I use in many parts of my application. I am sure I went about this wrong, but it was all I knew at the time. I am hoping someone is willing to take the time to show me how I should have done this and how I can wrap the `openStream` call in an `AsyncTask`. Thanks in advance for your help. Also, I have spent the last several days trying to figure it out on my own.

```
class Utilities {
    static XMLReader xr;
    static URL url;
    private final static int CHUNK_SIZE = 32 * 1024;
    static byte[] _fileIOBuffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];

static String DBGetOnlineVersionNumber(final Activity activity){

    final String version = null;

    try {

        /* Create a URL we want to load some xml-data from. */
        String location = activity.getString(R.string.version_file_location);
        url = new URL(location);

        /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

        /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
        xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader*/
        final XMLVersionReader myExampleHandler = new XMLVersionReader();
        xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

        xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream())); //Fails here
        /* Parsing has finished. */
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }
    return version;
}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to be passing around the Activity reference when all you really want is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have nicely put your code in a separate static method I'm guessing it's more appropriate to use it instead. Leaving you with possibility to call it synchronously or same code can be called from separate Thread. Wrapping the call into AsyncTask can be done somewhere around this if added to your Activity.

```
new AsyncTask<Activity, Void, String>() {
    @Override
    public String doInBackground(Activity... activities) {
        return Utilities.DBGetOnlineVersionNumber(activities[0]);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("VERSION_NUMBER", result);
    }
}.execute(this);
```

Comment: ill give this a shot and let you know. thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Can't promise this fixes your problem on Honeycomb though. But this is something I do quite often, write synchronous methods, and if needed call them from a separate Thread.

Comment: Works great. Thanks a bunch for your help and quick response.